# Turning type in a rectangle to a circle in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, transform

How is the below example achieved?

I'm assuming that the type would have been laid out normally within a rectangle and its interior lines, which would help the designer get the positioning and its balance right before then turning it into a circle. My question would be how is the linear composition then turned into a circle?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could create the artwork within a rectangle and warp it to the desired shape...

Take this example, which I've created in two halves:

[image]

I can then use a warp (*Object → Envelope Distory → Make with Warp...*) on one half to create a half circle and repeat for the other half, then place them together to get the full circle:

[image]

You can see by placing it inside an actual circle that the shape is far from perfect though:

[image]

You could manually create the warp shape better but that isn't as simple as it should be and you're still just distorting your artwork after the fact so you never really know what you'll end up with... Personally I would simply construct it how it's intended to be.

The type you can easily create by using the Type on a Path Tool on a circle and you can easily create most of your linework with circles and lines rotated around the center of your circle.

Setting up guidelines to work with like this is a pretty simple process:

[image]

If you have more complex sections that can't be easily constructed like this then you can create the smaller sections as rectangles...

[image]

...then use the guidelines to create more precise shapes to use to warp those sections (*Object → Envelope Distory → Make with Top Object*):

[image]

All in all I think it's best to be constructing your artwork as close to your desired outcome as possible and distorting as little as possible.